# Typedef to put units of measurement in C

Tags: c, data-structures, typedef

Is it good practice to use **typedef** for putting units of measurement into name? (and rename standard types) Like this:

```
typedef int16_t  MilliAmp_t;        /* 1 mA */
```

Comment: You are not "re-defining" anything, you are introducing a **new** name for the same type.

Comment: Not good enough; if you have another `typedef int16_t MicroAmp_t;`, then `MilliAmp_t` and `MicroAmp_t` could be used interchangeably.

Comment: As an interesting aside, [F# supports this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx).

Comment: I don't like this. It might be necessary to have voltage in `int16_t`, `uint32_t` and `float` at the same time in same project. You might be better off using strict coding conventions with Hungarian notation, (`int16_t mA_inputCurrent` for example). See [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

Comment: Please do not use `_t` for your own type names. Identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved by POSIX for system headers.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to add the unit to the variable name, than to the type, for example: `int16_t current_mA;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others point out `typedef` doesn't define a new type it introduces an alias.

If you really wanted this level of security then you can box values in a `struct`

```
typedef struct {
    int16_t v;

} MillAmp_t ;
```

It acquires a typing overhead:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int16_t v;

} MilliAmp_t ;

typedef struct {
    int16_t v;

} MilliOhms_t ;

typedef struct {
    int16_t v;

} MilliWatt_t ;


MilliWatt_t power_loss(MilliAmp_t current,MilliOhms_t resistance){
    //NB: Using int16_t makes this seriously under/overflow prone.
    //So we upsize everything for the best shot at a result.
    int64_t currentl=current.v;
    int64_t resistancel=resistance.v;
    int64_t result=currentl*currentl*resistancel/1000000L;
    return (MilliWatt_t){result};
}    

int main(void) {
    MilliAmp_t current={1000};
    MilliOhms_t resistance={2000};

    MilliWatt_t power=power_loss(current,resistance);

    printf("%d\n",(int)power.v);

    //MilliWatt_t rewop=power_loss(resistance,current);//Compiler Error! Hurray!!

    return 0;
}
```

But the overhead is not huge. You can wrap it up in a marco:

#define VALUE(S) ((S).v)

But I'm not convinced that helps.

Don't be automatically persuaded by people who tell you this solution isn't necessary. If your calculations are very complex involving lots of different units you could save yourself a lot of heartache for this modest overhead.

However the normal convention is to 'mangle' the unit into the names:

```
int16_ power_loss_MilliWatts(int16_t current_MilliAmps,int16_t resistance_MilliOhms);
```

That tends to help because programmers tend to refer to parameters by name and recognize the intent of that suffix. But obviously the compiler provides no oversight.

Before you ask, this 'boxing' is unlikely to have any overhead in memory or speed on any realistic compiler (certainly when compiled without debug).

PS: Anyone who refuses to accept this as even possibly worthwhile (in relevant circumstances) might amuse themselves with some classic unit conversion cock-ups.

http://mentalfloss.com/article/25845/quick-6-six-unit-conversion-disasters

There's also The Hubble Space Telescope and many other cock-ups.
I've seen a lot (a lot) of unit-test errors out by a factor of 100 because people use the terms percentage and factor loosely and interchangeably.

Answer (score 4):

You are just renaming some types. It does not bring any additional checks in the compiler (unless that compiler is customized specifically; if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could consider customizing it thru [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), but that customization is not a trivial task), in the sense that the following code

```
 MilliAmp_t x=0,y=1,z=2;
 x = y * z;
```

will always compile without warnings (in C) even if physically multiplying two currents and put the result in some current variable does not make any sense.

However, your typedef has a small *documentation* value: if you declare a prototype like

```
MilliWatt_t electical_power (MilliAmp_t current, MilliVolt_t tension);
```

then *some* readers might find that helpful (but perhaps not me).

Comment: *but perhaps not me* Me neither, I consider this as an unneeded level of type hiding.

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in significance from coding style side. Is it common?

Comment: @artsin Not uncommon. However, when I've personally written physical analysis code for small microcontrollers, I prefer to pick the range more carefully than just "1 step = 1 milliamp," so as to maximize precision. So I'd prefer just `voltage_t` and `current_t`, and then use global conversion coefficients when relating them to known physical quantities.

Comment: It _can_ add additional checks, either as some compiler feature not required by the standard, or when you run it through a static analysis tool.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, such typedefs are fairly common. Although C doesn't provide for strong typing that would prevent you from assigning a current quantity to a voltage variable, such a practice does allow you to see at a glance what a variable means without encoding that information into the name.

When I've personally written physical analysis code for small microcontrollers, I prefer to pick the range more carefully than just "1 step = 1 milliamp," so as to maximize precision. So, I'd prefer just `voltage_t` and `current_t`, and then use global conversion coefficients when relating them to known physical quantities.

Overflow and precision loss are important considerations when doing physical math with integers. Keeping variables in proper physical units tends to help keep intermediate results in a proper dynamic range, thus avoiding these problems, as long as the physical system keeps its voltages and currents within the range that you've chosen for uniform computational use.

If you *have* an FPU, I'd recommend using that, and don't bother with SI prefixes because it will handle milli-, micro-, and anything else transparently without mucking about with coefficients. Using `typedef double amps;` will still help code equations in a reasonable and expository way, and you can easily adjust the precision of the entire program later. By all means, do that.